# Anchor point gotoxy in c++

Tags: c++

My figure has a "Σ" shape. The problem is that I have to scale it from left upper corner instead of the middle, where the diagonals of this symbol are connecting.

I would really appreciate if anyone would mind to share any tips how to change it's anchor point for  either enlarging or reducing it's side. I'm thinking about this for almost week and can't get an idea what to change.

```
void figure(int &x1, int &x, int &y1, int &y, int &side, char &a, char &key) 
{
system("cls");

x1 = x; y1 = y;
gotoxy(x1, y1);
for (int i = 1; i <= side+ 10; i++) // upper figure edge
{
    cout << a;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= side; i++) // diagonal edge
{
    y1++;
    x1 = x + (i <= side / 2 ? i : (side - i + 1)) ;
    gotoxy(x1, y1);
    cout << a;
    x1 = x; 
}

y1++;
gotoxy(x1, y1);
for (int i = 1; i <= side + 10; i++) // bottom figure edge
    cout << a;
key = getch();
}



void enlarge_reduce(char &key, const int &console_size_x, const int &console_size_y, int &side, int &x, int &y, int &x1, int &y1) //enlarging and reducing figure size 
{
switch (key)
{
case '+':           // figure enlarge

    if (side <= (console_size_y <= console_size_x ? console_size_y - 4 : console_size_x - 4))
    {
        side += 2;
        --x;
        --y;
    }
    break;

case '-':           // reduce figure
    if (side > 4)
    {
        side -= 2;
        ++x; ++y;
    }
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: it seems that you're wanting to draw a scaled 2-d object in a cartesian co-ordinate space. You might find it helpful to take a look at some computer graphics fundamentals: http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm

Comment: Mmm to be more specific it's just a simple program in windows console written in MS VS 2013. Though the information is not useful for this project, I will save this site for my further progress with C++, since it seems to be really simple explained couple of thing i might need. Thanks for this site, tho still don't have an idea how to scale figure from other point. In picture below anchor point is in the middle while scaling but i want to be it in left upper figure corner and got no idea how to do it http://oi57.tinypic.com/o7mw74.jpg

Comment: I know what the program does. You want to draw a glyph on a Cartesian coordinate system (the console). The glyph is drawn as a result of a few operations against that system. To scale around a different point you have to translate the origin (vector add) then scale (vector multiply) then translate back (vector add).

Comment: Or not at all. So instead of gotoxy i have to set starting point for vector, and automatically base whole figure on vectores?

Comment: Or... nevermind! Got it :). Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Your figure() function uses the top left corner as the anchor point, not the middle.  Your enlarge_reduce() function is moving the top left corner.

Comment: So.. practically the figure even when it's scaling from the middle point it is scaling properly like it would be set for the top left corner? Because i want to make the top left symbol to be motionless.